# Two-Stage Utility Maximization Problem

Tags: microeconomics, optimization, demand

[image]

Actually I don't know how to solve such utility maximization problem, only know using FOC and budget constraint to solve for demand. I will appreciate it if someone tell me the procedure facing such problem.

Comment: It is [quasilinear utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasilinear_utility#:~:text=In%20economics%20and%20consumer%20theory,the%20Marshallian%2FWalrasian%20demand%20for). What have you tried?

Comment: "using FOC and budget constraint to solve for demand" would work here for each good, so go for it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasilinear_utility) (take from Hal Varian's book) of a quasi-linear utility function

$$u(w,x_1,...,x_n) = w + h(x_1,...,x_n),$$

where $h$ is strictly concave.

The example in this exercise is according to this definition not a quasi-linear utility function because $h(x_1,...,x_n)$, which in this case is $x_2^\alpha x_3^{1-\alpha}$ is not **strictly** concave but instead concave. This is so because $x_2^\alpha x_3^{1-\alpha}$ has exponents that sum to 1 instead of being less than one.

The case under consideration is closer to that of perfect substitutes. However, it is a little more complicated because one of the goods is a composite good.

You need to know two things in order to solve the exercise:

**A. You need to know how to solve the case of perfect substitutes**

**B. You need to know how to solve the case of CD preferences**

Consider first the case of perfect substitutes

$$\max_{x_1,z}\ \ u(x_1,z) = x_1 + \bar a z \\ s.t. \ \ x_1 + p_zz = I$$

for each coin spend on $x_1$ the agent gets 1 utility point and for each $p_z$ coins spent on $z$ the agent gets $\bar a$ utility points which amounts to $\bar a/p_z$ utility point per coin. Hence if $1>\bar a/p_z$ the agent will only buy $x_1$ and demand for $x_1$ is simply $I$ units because the price of $x_1$ is standardized to $1$. If $1<\bar a/p_z$ the agent will only buy $z$ and the demand for $I/p_z$. Finally, if $1=\bar a/p_z$ the agent is indifferent between $x_1$ and $z$ and the demand for $x_1$ is then any amount of units in $[0,I]$ with the demand for $z$ being $(I-x_1)/p_z$.

Consider next the case of CD-preferences with

$$h(x_2,x_3) = \left(\frac{x_2}{\alpha}\right)^\alpha \left(\frac{x_3}{1-\alpha}\right)^{1-\alpha}$$

Note that the function is homogenous of degree 1 hence has constants returns to scale. In this case, there exists a price for each utility point which can be found by solving the expenditure minimization problem

$$\min_{x_2,x_3} \ \ p_{2}x_2 + p_{3} x_3 \\ s.t. \ \ \left(\frac{x_2}{\alpha}\right)^\alpha \left(\frac{x_3}{1-\alpha}\right)^{1-\alpha} = z$$

when solving this problem you will get the expenditure function

$$E_h(p_{2},p_{3},z) = (p_{2}^\alpha p_{3}^{1-\alpha}) z,$$

which tells you that for each utility point $z$ the consumer must pay $p_{2}^\alpha p_{3}^{1-\alpha}$. Because expenditure is proportional to $z$ with the constant of proportionality being $p_{2}^\alpha p_{3}^{1-\alpha}$ you can conceive of $p_{2}^\alpha p_{3}^{1-\alpha}$ as the price per utility point $z$. I therefore adopt the definition

$$p_z := p_{2}^\alpha p_{3}^{1-\alpha},$$

in which case the expenditure function becomes

$$E_h(p_{2},p_{3},z) = p_z z.$$

---

Let us now finally consider the problem in the assignment

$$\max_{x_1,x_2,x_3} \ \ x_1 + x_2^\alpha x_3^{1-\alpha} \\ s.t. \ \ x_1 + p_2x_2 + p_3x_3 = I.$$

You can multiply and divide the second summand of the utility function with $\alpha^\alpha$ and $(1-\alpha)^{1-\alpha}$ to get

$$ x_1 + \bar a \underbrace{\left[\left(\frac{x_2}{\alpha}\right)^\alpha \left(\frac{x_3}{1-\alpha}\right)^{1-\alpha}\right]}_{:=z} = x_1 + \bar a z$$

where $\bar a=\alpha^\alpha (1-\alpha)^{1-\alpha}$.

You can now see that the agent faces the choice of spending money on $x_1$ getting one utility point per coin or spending money on $x_2$ and $x_3$ getting $\bar a$ utility points per $p_z = p_2^\alpha p_3^{1-\alpha}$ coins. Using the logic from the case of perfect substitutes it follows that if

$$1>\bar a/p_z = \alpha^\alpha(1-\alpha)^{1-\alpha}/(p_2^\alpha p_3^{1-\alpha})$$

the consumer only spends money on $x_1$ and demand is $x_1(p_1,p_2,p_3,I) = I$ while $x_2(p_1,p_2,p_3,I) = x_3(p_1,p_2,p_3,I) =0$.

In the case where

$$1<\bar a/p_z = \alpha^\alpha(1-\alpha)^{1-\alpha}/(p_2^\alpha p_3^{1-\alpha})$$

the consumer spend all money on $z$ which is $x_2$ and $x_3$ and as always with CD preferences $\alpha$ share is spent on $x_2$ and $(1-\alpha)$ share on $x_3$ so the demand is

$x_1(p_1,p_2,p_3,I) = 0$ while $x_2(p_1,p_2,p_3,I) = \frac{\alpha I}{p_2}$ and $x_3(p_1,p_2,p_3,I) =\frac{(1-\alpha)I}{p_3}$.

Finally, in the case where

$$1=\bar a/p_z = \alpha^\alpha(1-\alpha)^{1-\alpha}/(p_2^\alpha p_3^{1-\alpha})$$

it does not matter how the consumer allocates spending between $x_1$ and $z$, but any amount spent on $z$ is spent on $x_2$ and $x_3$ and must be distributed between $x_2$ and $x_3$ optimally. Hence, demand for $x_1(p_1,p_2,p_3,I) \in [0,I]$ and $x_2(p_1,p_2,p_3,I) = \frac{\alpha(I-x_1)}{p_2}$ while $x_3(p_1,p_2,p_3,I) = \frac{(1-\alpha)(I-x_1)}{p_3}$.

---

You will have trouble using FOC's because they do not capture the border solution where the consumer chooses to spend all money on $x_1$ or on the combined good $z$ that is $x_2$ and $x_3$.