Maximisation of nested utility function with 2 constraints
I apologise for any improper use of terminology/notation as I only have a very rudimentary understanding of the topic. I would like to know how to solve the following utility maximisation problem concerning intrahousehold resource allocation:
The mother’s and father’s utilities enter into the collective utility function, which has a simple Cobb Douglas form, where $\mu$ denotes mothers Pareto weight, and $1-\mu$ is that of the father:
max $U=u_m^{\mu}u_f^{(1-\mu)}$.
The parental sub-utility functions, nested in the household utility function, both take on the CES form, in which parents decide the amount of human capital X of child 1 and child 2 that would maximize their individual utility. The problem thus only concerns the allocation of resources towards two public goods. a and $\rho$ are the mother’s preference for child 1 and degree of inequality aversion, respectively. b and $\sigma$ serve the same roles in the father’s sub utility:
$u_m=(aX_1^\rho+(1-a)X_2^\rho)^\frac{1}{\rho}$
$u_f=(bX_1^\sigma+(1-b)X_2^\sigma)^\frac{1}{\sigma}$.
s.t. the two children’s human capital production function, also of a Cobb Douglas functional form:
$X_1=A_1h_1^ce^{1-c}_1$
$X_2=A_2h_2^ce^{1-c}_2$
where A is the child’s genetic endowments, and h and e each denotes the amount of health and education inputs going into the production function of the child.
also s.t.
$M=P_{h_1}h_1+P_{h_2}h_2+P_{e_1}e_1+P_{e_2}e_2$,
Where P denotes price of the input its subscript corresponds to. The share of the budget the mother has control over in her subutility maximization is $\mu$, and for the father, $1-\mu$.
I would like to solve for the ratio of health/education input of child 1 to child 2.

Hi: It's best to give the dimensions of the variables ( like $n \times 1$ or whatever ) and also their meanings. For example, $P_{x}$ probably denotes the projection but I'm not certain. Also, you should explain what's known and what's not. For example, what are the $h's$ and the $e's$. All of this will give you a greater chance of getting a response.

Thank you so much for the suggestions.

It is super tedious. Have you derived the expenditure functions for the CES and CD utility?

To solve the utility maximization problem you need to follow the money.
The total income is $M$ which is split between the mother and father according to the Pareto weights $\mu$ and $(1-\mu)$. This implies that $\mu M$ is used on $u_m$ and $(1-\mu)M$ on $u_f$.
The income $\mu M$ is split by the mother on $X_1$ for child $1$ and $X_2$ for child $2$. Let $s_1^m$ be the share of mother income $\mu M$ used on $X_1$ and $s_2^m$ the share of $\mu M$ used on $X_2$. Similarly, let $s_1^f$ and $s_2^f$ be the same shares for the case of the father.
The mother therefore uses $s_1^m\mu M$ on $X_1^m$ (subscript to indicate it is $X_1$ paid by the mother) and $s_2^m\mu M$ on $X_2^m$. Similarly, for the father $s_1^f(1-\mu)M$ used on $X_1^f$ and $s_2^f(1-\mu) M$ used on $X_2^f$.
Finally, whatever is spent on $X_1$ is spent partly on $h_1$ and partly on $e_1$ by the shares $c$ and $(1-c)$ by both the mother and the father.
Hence, the mothers demand for $h_1$ is given as
$$h_1^m = \frac{cs_1^m \mu M}{P_{h_1}},$$
and the mother demand for $e_1$ is given as
$$e_1^m = \frac{(1-c)s_1^m \mu M}{P_{e_1}},$$
The mothers demand for $h_2$ is given as
$$h_2^m = \frac{cs_2^m \mu M}{P_{h_2}},$$
and the mother demand for $e_1$ is given as
$$e_2^m = \frac{(1-c)s_2^m \mu M}{P_{e_2}},$$
and the fathers' demands are the same just with $(1-\mu)$ instead of $\mu$ and the fathers shares $s_1^f$ and $s_2^f$.
The shares $s_1^m,s_1^f,s_2^m,s_2^f$ are found by solving the CES utility maximization problem and the expenditure minimization problem of the CD utility.
The Marshall demand for a CES utility function of the form
$$(kZ_1^\alpha + (1-k)Z_2^{1-\alpha})^{1/\alpha}$$
Can be written as
$$Z_1^\star =\left[ \frac{k^\alpha P_{Z_1}^{1-\alpha}}{k^\alpha P_{Z_1}^{1-\alpha} + (1-k)^\alpha P_{Z_2}^{1-\alpha}}\right]  \frac{I}{P_{Z_1}} $$
$$Z_2^\star =\left[ \frac{(1-k)^\alpha P_{Z_2}^{1-\alpha}}{k^\alpha P_{Z_1}^{1-\alpha} + (1-k)^\alpha P_{Z_2}^{1-\alpha}}\right]  \frac{I}{P_{Z_2}},$$
where the terms in the brackets are the shares (see for example this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhxprnW2Sc4).
To solve for the share $s_1^m$ do the following:
(1) Let $P_{Z_1}$ and $P_{Z_2}$ be $P_{X_1}$ and $P_{X_2}$
(2) Let $k=a$ and
(3) Let $\alpha=\rho$
To get
$$s_1^m = \left[ \frac{a^\rho P_{X_1}^{1-\rho}}{a^\rho P_{X_1}^{1-\rho} + (1-a)^\rho P_{X_2}^{1-\rho}}\right],$$
Finally, to get the price of $X_1$ and $X_2$ you need the expenditure function of the CD functions $A_1h_1^ce_1^{1-c}$ and $A_2h_2^ce_2^{1-c}$. I will derive this by assuming the income is $E$ and then use the Marshall demands to get the value function which I then invert to get the expenditure function.
The value function for $A_1h_1^ce_1^{1-c}$ is
$$V(P_{h_1},P_{e_1},E) = \frac{A_1c^c(1-c)^{1-c}}{P_{h_1}^cP_{e_1}^{1-c}} E,$$
so the expenditure function is
$$E = \frac{P_{h_1}^cP_{e_1}^{1-c}}{A_1c^c(1-c)^{1-c}} V,$$
which tells you that the price for $X_1$ utility point $V$ is simply
$$P_{X_1} = \frac{P_{h_1}^cP_{e_1}^{1-c}}{A_1c^c(1-c)^{1-c}},$$
by the same argument the price $P_{X_2}$ is found to be
$$P_{X_2} = \frac{P_{h_2}^cP_{e_2}^{1-c}}{A_2c^c(1-c)^{1-c}},$$
you can then back insert these into the expression for $s_1^m$.
Note that the prices of $P_{X_1}$ and $P_{X_2}$ are the same for the mother and father and only depend on exogenously given constants.
You have to do this for the rest of the shares as well ... but I leave that as an exercise for you.
PS. To derive health ratio
$$\lambda := \frac{h_1}{h_2} = \frac{h_1^f + h_1^m}{h_2^f + h_2^m}$$
$$h_1^m + h_1^f= \frac{cM(s_1^m\mu  +s_1^f(1-\mu))}{P_{h_1}},$$
$$h_2^m + h_2^f= \frac{cM(s_2^m\mu  +s_2^f(1-\mu))}{P_{h_2}},$$
$$\lambda = \frac{P_{h_2}}{P_{h_1}}\frac{(s_1^m\mu  +s_1^f(1-\mu))}{(s_2^m\mu  +s_2^f(1-\mu))}$$

Thank you so, so much for providing this explanation with the utmost clarity.

You are welcome. Maybe you will also find this interesting: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/50478/two-stage-utility-maximization-problem/50482#50482. And if you like the answer you may consider accepting it.

Done! Thanks a lot again. If it is ok, I would like to followup with another (perhaps very dumb) question. If I was to derive the ratio of the amount of health input of child 1 to child 2, would the correct approach be substituting $P_{X_1}$ and $P_{X_2}$ back into $s_1^m$, $s_2^m$, $s_1^f$ and $s_2^f$ as you mentioned, then substitute those into $\frac{h_1}{h_2}$, obtained from $\frac{h_1^m+h_1^f}{h_2^m+h_2^f}$?

Yes, that is correct. Use exogenous parameters to calculate $P_{X_1}$ and $P_{X_2}$ then calculate shares using further exogenous parameters and prices and finally calculate the health ratio $\lambda$ as added that to the question.

Sorry, I no longer follow what you are trying to achieve. I suggest  you open a follow up question if further clarification is needed.

Yeah I realised it made little sense so I deleted it right after(seems like it went through anyway). Sorry for the trouble, and thank you again for the assistance.
